# Creating View with 2 columns in swift

Tags: swift

I'm starting with swift and I would like to make a vocabulary app, where you have 2 columns, but don't know which View to use. Neither Table View or Collection View have exactly two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Table View**

In Table View there is no delegate method to get columns. Either you need to use two table views side by side to make columns effect(But it's not recommended) or by customizing table view cell(i.e., placing two labels on a row).

**Using Collection View**

Refer this link: [Specify row and column number for UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010335/specify-row-and-column-number-for-uicollectionview)

This link also might useful for you :http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-collection-view-using-swift/

Comment: thanks, the first link helped

Answer (score 1):

Use `UICollectionView`, create a custom layout to fit your need.